# como usar as informações de uma api em uma tag com props

Tags: javascript, react, api

eu quero fazer os valores da minha api aparecer no meu componente card, como podem ver eu tentei o props no componente Card mas ele da erro, diz que o valor esta indefinido, e esta porque o valor so chega depois que o usuário põem o nome de usuário dele do github.

```
arquivo  index.jsx 

    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Card } from "../../components/Card";
    
    function App() {
      const [name, setName] = useState();
      const [collection, setCollection] = useState([]); 
      const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: "",
        avatar: "",
        location: "",
        followers: 0,
      });
      function handleAddPerson(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const newName = {
          name: name,
          user: user
        };
        setCollection((prevState) => [...prevState, newName]); 
        
          fetch("https://api.github.com/users/${user}")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              console.log("hey");
              setUser({
                name: data.name,
                avatar: data.avatar_url,
                location: data.location,
                followers: data.followers,
                text: console.log("hey set")
              });
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
     }
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <h1>anything</h1>
    
          <strong>{user.name}</strong>
          <img src={user.avatar} alt="one p" />
          <strong>{user.location}</strong>
          <strong>{user.followers}</strong>
          
          <form action="" onSubmit={handleAddPerson}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Name..."
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Github User"
              onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
            />
    
            <button type="submit">ADD</button>
          </form>
    
          {collection.map((person) => (
            <Card
              name={person.name}
              key={person.userGit}
              user={person.userGit}
              avatar={person.avatar}
              location={person.location}
              followers={person.followers}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

arquivo Card.jsx

```
    export function Card(props){
    
    
        return (
          <>
            <div className="card">
              <p>{props.name}</p>
              <p>{props.userGit}</p>
              <img src={props.avatar} alt="one p" />
              <p>{props.location}</p>
              <p>{props.followers}</p>
            </div>
          </>
        );
    }
```

olá o código como um todo funciona infelizmente eu não consegui explicar da melhor maneira mas eu consigo extrair informação da api mesmo sem usar async wait, o que eu quero realmente fazer é por as informações que vem da api dentro do meu card.

[image: Foto do código em ação]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPGrz.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPGrz.jpg

eu consigo botar as informações do github, mas quero que elas fiquem dentro da parte que é o card (a parte roxa), como podem ver o card é um arquivo diferente que esta sendo exportado, eu falo sobre props na minha pergunta porque é isso que estou usando no card. espero ter sido mais clara obrigada.

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que jogar o objeto que tu monta com o retorno da API no setCollection, pois é o collection que você usa pra popular o card, como tu ta adicionando o preenchimento dos inputs no collection, o restante das props estarão realmente indefinidas.

Comment: olá fiz uma edição na minha pergunta espero ter sido mais clara. obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o principal problema seja no seu método `handleAddPerson`, ele está adicionando um objeto incompleto com o que é usado no Card, o erro pode ser por causa disso.
Acho que um fluxo melhor para o método seria fazer a busca de dados na API do Github e posteriormente adicionar o objeto a collection.
Além disso, na minha opinião os dois inputs são desnecessários, já que você apenas utiliza o valor de um para fazer a busca.
Acho igualmente desnecessário o primeira parte do retorno onde você coloca os `strong` e  `img` já que o card tem esse papel, né?

Vi também que você está usando o nome de usuário como "key" do card, como a API do Github traz o id do usuário, você pode usar essa propriedade para o key, acho que seria a melhor maneira também. Essa alteração eu não fiz no seu código, mas recomendo.

Segue exemplo de código abaixo do que eu acho que seria o mais eficiente com o que você está querendo fazer.
Como não conseguir testar, peço que qualquer erro que obtenha descreva ele aqui para que possamos ajudar da melhor maneira.
Espero ter ajudado! :D

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Card } from "../../components/Card";

function App() {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState();
    const [collection, setCollection] = useState([]);

    function handleAddPerson(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch("https://api.github.com/users/${userName}")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                const newUser = {
                    name: data.name,
                    userGit: data.login,//propriedade adicionada pois existe em card
                    avatar: data.avatar_url,
                    location: data.location,
                    followers: data.followers
                }
                setCollection((prevState) => [...prevState, newUser]);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>anything</h1>
            
            <form action="" onSubmit={handleAddPerson}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Github User"
                    onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
                />

                <button type="submit">ADD</button>
            </form>

            {collection.map((person) => (
                <Card
                    name={person.name}
                    key={person.userGit}
                    user={person.userGit}
                    avatar={person.avatar}
                    location={person.location}
                    followers={person.followers}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```